# How can I run php on the command line?

Tags: php, windows

I have a php class file, and I want to find out how I can run it on the Windows command line.  Do I need to install something?  Are there any tutorials?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have PHP already installed for windows use this to run a file:

```
php.exe -f myfile.php
```

More detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you: [Install windows commandline](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Command Line switch to the folder where your php class is located. then type the path to your php.exe and give the class file as parameter. Try googling for "Add PHP to Path" to get some information how to do this with like 'php file.class.php'

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Install xampp and then read this:

http://www.blog.highub.com/php/running-php-using-windows-command-line-with-xampp/

Comment: If he only needs a php.exe then installing all of XAMPP is overkill.